# How to change a custom chekout field from text to text area in WooCommerce

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

How can I change `billing_options` custom checkout field from Text to Text Area in WooCommerce on the checkout page?

Here is the HTML output:

```html
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_options" id="billing_options" placeholder="توضیحات (اختیاری)" value="">
```

[image]

Comment: First, how your custom checkout field `billing_options` is implemented in WooCommerce on your website? Without that information, nobody is going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can channge it by add this code in `function.php`

```
// Change address field at checkout
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'abukotsh_change_address_input_type', 10, 1 );
 
function abukotsh_change_address_input_type( $fields ) {
$fields['billing']['billing_options']['type'] = 'textarea';
return $fields;
}
```

Comment: ow your custom checkout field billing_options is implemented in WooCommerce on your website